# css overflow scroll table cell with width:auto or width:100%

Tags: css, scroll, html-table, width, overflow

I would like to build flexible layout with scrollbars and dynamic widths.

I have table width,height 100% of window and 2(3) columns with auto widths ( widths depends on it's content ) and center column with remaining width. I can't specify exact width of column.

I would like to have Horizontal and Vertical Scrollbars if my content bigger than cell width and height;

**Example 1**
[image: Example 2]

**Example 2**
Here is [LiveDemo](http://jsbin.com/zofola/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
<div style="width:1024px">
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
       <td>
           <div>Column Menu with Dynamic Content and width</div>
       </td>
       <td style="width:100%;">
           <div style="overflow:scroll;">Column Big Dynamic Content with ScrollBars</div>           
       </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

I can't use :

1. `table-layout:fixed` - because columns width depends on it's content
2. `overflow:scroll` with `width,height` specified
3. i need pure css solution

I've tried :

1. `width:100%, max-width:100%, min-width:100%` - not working
2. `white-space:wrap` works only if content is text, and there is only vertical scrollbar

**Question is :** How to make `div` with `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto` have `width,height` of it's parent container ( in my case it is `TD` )

p.s 
**BEST case would be if it was** `<TD style="overflow:auto"></TD>` and width is auto.

Comment: if the columns width depends on the content then how will it know when to scroll?  Also how can you have 2 columns but one of them is 100%. Also is this tabular data?  If not, I would use display:flex and divs, would be much easier to achieve what you want

Comment: If you run example, you will see if table columns has auto width, it width will be calculated from width of content. It;s for first column, for second column width will be remaining of total width of table

Comment: Ok, run your example and take off that 200px, you see the first column shrinks rather than grows, the only way that will grow with the 100% being on the other column is if it is an image or if you have white-space nowrap;

Answer (score 2):

Found **second solution ( more prettier )**, and it works!

Here on stackoverflow there are solutions saying add child div to td with height,width, and overflow scroll, but they all not working with dynamic widths of cells, so **I slightly modified solution by adding to** div `position:absolute` and set `top,bottom,right,left to 0`, and adding to parent container `position:relative;`

Here is [Live Demo 1](http://output.jsbin.com/rorede)

```
    <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
      <tr>
        <td> <!-- left column with autowidth -->
            <div style="width:200px">Left Menu</div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:100%; position:relative;"> <!-- fill remaing width of columns -->
          <div style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; overflow:auto; ">
            <div style="width:1000px; height:1000px; background:#f05555;">Calendar Mega BIG content</div>
          </div>
        </td>
         <td> <!-- right column with autowidth -->
            <div style="width:300px">Right Menu</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

If we go further and be more modern ( in life without tables ), it would be like this :

Here is [Live Demo 2](http://jsbin.com/ziravin/edit?html,output)

```
    <ul style="width:100%; height:100%; display:table;">
        <li style="display:table-cell;"> <!-- left column with autowidth -->
            <div style="width:200px">Left Menu</div>
        </li>
        <li style="display:table-cell; width:100%; position:relative;"> <!-- fill remaing width of columns -->
          <div style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; overflow:auto;">
            <div style="width:1000px; height:1000px; background:#f05555;">Calendar Mega BIG content</div>
          </div>
        </li>
         <li style="display:table-cell;"> <!-- right column with autowidth -->
            <div style="width:300px">Right Menu</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Found ( Ugly ) solution, but it works!**

Basic idea, is to **wrap scrollable content inside one more table** with `table-layout:fixed`, leaving outer table with dynamic widths :)

Here is [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/hagewid/edit?html,output)

[image]

```
  <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
          <div style="width:200px">Left Menu</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 100%;">
          <table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
          <tr><td>
              <div style="overflow:auto; width:100%; height:100%;">
                <div style="width:1000px; height:1000px; background:#f0f0f0;">Calendar</div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
       <td>
          <div style="width:300px">Right Menu</div>
      </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

**If you find better solution**, without much markup tags, please welcome to post here...!

p.s I think i should try play with `display:table` or `flex` to achieve more elegant solution